# How to snap an NSWindow to a grid

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grid, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

How can I snap an NSWindow to a grid? Any good algorithms, tutorials that are recommended?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to monitor you app's windows its easy to just monitor the own windows locations and "override" their locations as soon as they come to a grid boundary. You might want to checkout the [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) documentation for observing `NSWindow` properties.

What I think you actually want to do is monitor ALL windows, including those from other apps. If so, have a look at Apples [Accessibility](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXIntro/OSXAXintro.html) APIs.

Keep in mind when you use AX APIs you have to either enable accessibility support in the system preferences or authorize your app!

Update:

---

Example: http://toxicsoftware.com/snappingwindow_cocoa_source_code/

Comment: My app has many floating windows and a main canvas window where I want to snap them to. How would I go about setting up the grid?